# How to merge develop by using "integrate develop" into local branch in smart git

Tags: git, smartgit

I am new to using smart git. I usually create a feature from the git flow process of smart git and I usually get an "integrate develop" option to merge my local branch with updated develop branch. I however did not create my present branch as a feature, so I don't get that option when I right click on the local branch. How do I merge my develop branch into my current working local branch?

Comment: If you did not create a feature branch, which branch is your "local branch" then?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  the local branch name is "improve_ux"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SmartGit's **Integrate Develop** is basically a `git rebase` or `git merge`. Hence, with a non-Git-Flow branch, first make sure your local branch (which should have been a feature) is checked out. Then right-click `develop` from the **Branches** view and select either **Merge** or **Rebase HEAD to**.